# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement <package>

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

I'm installing several Python packages in Ubuntu 12.04 using the following `requirements.txt` file:

```
numpy>=1.8.2,<2.0.0
matplotlib>=1.3.1,<2.0.0
scipy>=0.14.0,<1.0.0
astroML>=0.2,<1.0
scikit-learn>=0.14.1,<1.0.0
rpy2>=2.4.3,<3.0.0
```

and these two commands:

```
$ pip install --download=/tmp -r requirements.txt
$ pip install --user --no-index --find-links=/tmp -r requirements.txt
```

(the first one downloads the packages and the second one installs them).

The process is frequently stopped with the error:

```
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement <package> (from matplotlib<2.0.0,>=1.3.1->-r requirements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for <package> (from matplotlib<2.0.0,>=1.3.1->-r requirements.txt (line 2))
```

which I fix manually with:

```
pip install --user <package>
```

and then run the second `pip install` command again.

But that only works for *that* particular package. When I run the second `pip install` command again, the process is stopped now complaining about *another* required package and I need to repeat the process again, ie: install the new required package manually (with the command above) and then run the second `pip install` command.

So far I've had to manually install `six`, `pytz`, `nose`, and now it's complaining about needing `mock`.

Is there a way to tell `pip` to automatically install *all* needed dependencies so I don't have to do it manually one by one?

**Add**: This only happens in Ubuntu 12.04 BTW. In Ubuntu 14.04 the `pip install` commands applied on the `requirements.txt` file work without issues.

Comment: Sometimes your Django project may depend on local brew packages. Double check you have these installed!

Comment: i had the same issue, with 'python -m pip install flask' i was able to install it

Comment: did you check the version of python your env is using matches the python reqs of the project? If not it seems you get this error. I fixed it with `conda create -n my_anatome_env python=3.9;
conda activate my_anatome_env
` for example then doing the pip install.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

This approach (having all dependencies in a directory and not downloading from an index) only works when the directory contains all packages. The directory should therefore contain all dependencies but also all packages that those dependencies depend on (e.g., `six`, `pytz` etc).

You should therefore manually include these in `requirements.txt` (so that the first step downloads them explicitly) or you should install all packages using PyPI and then `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to store the list of all packages needed.

Comment: So the only way to find out which *all* the requirements are is to `freeze` the installed packages in a working set up and then add everything in there to the `requirements.txt` file?

Comment: @Gabriel: currently yes as many Python packages are installed by running a `setup.py` file which contains the dependencies that they need. This should get better once Python package become wheel files (http://pythonwheels.com) which allow you to gather a list of all needed packages without executing arbitrary code in `setup.py` files.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Simeon. One more thing if you don't mind: why does this not happen in Ubuntu 14.04 but it does in Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: @Gabriel: I'm not sure - in my experience `pip` always aborts when it can't find a package to install. That being said `pip` is actively being developed so it could be that you have a version that I haven't worked with.

Comment: @SimeonVisser, "[wheels] allow you to gather a list of all needed packages without executing arbitrary code", interesting, mind sharing how to actually do that (by now)?

Comment: In my case, if it helps someone. I was getting exactly the same error, trying to run: `pip3 install json`. Then realised that json is part of cpython, so it was already there not needed to be "installed"

Comment: wish the error message told me it was due to a python version mistmatch. Why does it not say that explicitly?

Answer (score 126):

*Although it doesn't really answers this specific question. Others got the same error message with this mistake.*

For those who like me initial forgot the `-r`: Use `pip install -r requirements.txt` the `-r` is essential for the command.

The original answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42876654/10093070

Comment: wish the error message told me it was due to a python version mistmatch. Why does it not say that explicitly?

Answer (score 112):

I had installed python3 but my python in `/usr/bin/python` was still the old 2.7 version

This worked (`<pkg>` was `pyserial` in my case):

```
python3 -m pip install <pkg>
```

Comment: this happens when in setuptools there is `python_requires='>=3.0'` as requirement

Comment: an easy way to check whether this applies to you is to see if there's a directory mismatch between `which python` and `which pip`

Comment: replacing `pip` with `pip3` worked for me as well

Comment: wish the error message told me it was due to a python version mistmatch. Why does it not say that explicitly?

Comment: This gave me a segfault on kubuntu 22 : (

Answer (score 29):

Just a reminder to whom google this error and come here.

Let's say I get this error:

```
$ python3 example.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 7, in <module>
    import aalib
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aalib'
```

Since it mentions `aalib`, I was thought to try `aalib`:

```
$ python3.8 -m pip install aalib
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement aalib (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for aalib
```

But it actually **wrong package name**, ensure `pip search`([service disabled](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5216#issuecomment-744605466) at the time of writing), or google, or search on [pypi site](https://pypi.org/) to get the **accurate package name**:

[image]

Then install successfully:

```
$ python3.8 -m pip install python-aalib
Collecting python-aalib
  Downloading python-aalib-0.3.2.tar.gz (14 kB)
...
```

---

As `pip --help` stated:

```
$ python3.8 -m pip --help
...
  -v, --verbose               Give more output. Option is additive, and can be used up to 3 times.
```

To have a systematic way to figure out the root causes instead of rely on luck, you can append `-vvv` option of `pip` command to see details, e.g.:

```
$ python3.8 -u -m pip install aalib -vvv
User install by explicit request
Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-b3ghm9eb
Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-req-tracker-ygwnj94r
Initialized build tracking at /tmp/pip-req-tracker-ygwnj94r
Created build tracker: /tmp/pip-req-tracker-ygwnj94r
Entered build tracker: /tmp/pip-req-tracker-ygwnj94r
Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-install-jfurrdbb
1 location(s) to search for versions of aalib:
* https://pypi.org/simple/aalib/
Fetching project page and analyzing links: https://pypi.org/simple/aalib/
Getting page https://pypi.org/simple/aalib/
Found index url https://pypi.org/simple
Getting credentials from keyring for https://pypi.org/simple
Getting credentials from keyring for pypi.org
Looking up "https://pypi.org/simple/aalib/" in the cache
Request header has "max_age" as 0, cache bypassed
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.org:443
https://pypi.org:443 "GET /simple/aalib/ HTTP/1.1" 404 13
[hole] Status code 404 not in (200, 203, 300, 301)
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/aalib/: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/aalib/ - skipping
Given no hashes to check 0 links for project 'aalib': discarding no candidates
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement aalib (from versions: none)
Cleaning up...
Removed build tracker: '/tmp/pip-req-tracker-ygwnj94r'
ERROR: No matching distribution found for aalib
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 186, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 357, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 177, in resolve
    discovered_reqs.extend(self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 333, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 281, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    req.populate_link(self.finder, upgrade_allowed, require_hashes)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 249, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py", line 926, in find_requirement
    raise DistributionNotFound(
pip._internal.exceptions.DistributionNotFound: No matching distribution found for aalib
```

From above log, there is pretty obvious the URL `https://pypi.org/simple/aalib/` 404 not found. Then you can guess the possible reasons which cause that 404, i.e. wrong package name. Another thing is I can modify relevant python files of pip modules to further debug with above log. To edit `.whl` file, you can [use `wheel` command to `unpack` and `pack`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55031535/1074998).

Comment: Usually, it's also incorrect version installation, be on the check for the releases of the package

Comment: `pip search` no longer works.  See below:


`RuntimeError: PyPI no longer supports 'pip search' (or XML-RPC search). Please use https://pypi.org/search (via a browser) instead. See https://warehouse.pypa.io/api-reference/xml-rpc.html#deprecated-methods for more information.`

Answer (score 20):

I found a way to fix it with just one line of command. You need to know the version of the package (Just search up PACKAGE version).

Command:

```sh
python3 -m pip install --pre --upgrade PACKAGE==VERSION.VERSION.VERSION
```

Answer (score 7):

Not always, but in some cases the package already exists. For example - getpass. It is not listed by "pip list" but it can be imported and used:

[image]

If I try to pip install getpass I get the following error:
"Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement getpass"

Answer (score 4):

Try installing flask through the powershell using the following command.

```
pip install --isolated Flask
```

This will allow installation to avoide environment variables and user configuration.

Answer (score 4):

If you facing this issue at the workplace. This might be the solution for you.

```
pip install -U <package_name> --user --proxy=<your proxy>
```

Answer (score 4):

###### Since it's a pretty annoying problem that may stuck beginners for a long period of time, here I write a complete guild.

> if you are running `pip install PACKAGE` or `python -m pip install PACKAGE`, and a `no matching version found` error reported, here's how to solve the problem.

1. search your package on browser, for example my package is `pycypto`, here I search `pycypto pypi`
2. find your package, open the link on pypi, click **download file**
3. open a python shell, import any of your installed package, for example, I have installed Pillow before.

```py
>>> import PIL
>>> PIL.__path__
['/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/canvas/src/zzd/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL']
```

`PACKAGE.__path__` function will gives you the `side packages` path where all packages should go into.

PLUS:
if you have no idea what packages you installed before, run `pip list` to get a list of installed packages.

4. after we obtain the path, open a shell, cd to the path

```sh
cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/canvas/src/zzd/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/
open
```

5. unzip the downloaded file, drag it into `site-packages`.
6. cd into the downloaded directory, and run `setup.py` to install

```sh
cd pycrypto-2.6.1
python setup.py install
```

Then you should be able to import and use the package in python.

Answer (score 3):

Pip install from pypi.org.

```
pip install -U -i  https://pypi.org/simple package
```

Comment: Better add one liner explaining the flags. `-U, --upgrade`: Upgrade all specified packages to the newest available version.  And `-i,   --index-url <url>`: Base URL of the Python Package Index (default https://pypi.org/simple).

Answer (score 3):

#### One possible error, pip package requires python intepreter which you are not using.

I ran into the same problem, it occurred only when I ran commands from my Docker image (or Dockerfile). Finally many hours later I managed to solve it by updating my python intepreter. Pointed out that my pip-package required python>=3,7 but my Docker image was using python 3.6.

Tip: To check out if you have similar problem, just check pip package requirements and your python version. Private pip package intepreter requirements are wrote down inside setup.py or setup.cfg. Public pip packages are usuially hosted in pypi.org where you can just check intepreter requirements with your browser. To check your python intepreter version just write for example python --version or python3 --version in your console

#### General problem description

As other answers point out there can also be other requirements that you are not satisfying and that is why pip can not found suitable package version for you. All the requirements are wrote down in pip package documentation and can be easily readed from https://pypi.org/project/graphene-django/your-package

Answer (score 2):

I got this error while installing `awscli` on Windows 10 in anaconda (python 3.7).
While troubleshooting, I went to the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49991357/6862405 and then to https://stackoverflow.com/a/54582701/6862405. Finally found that I need to install the libraries `PyOpenSSL`, `cryptography`, `enum34`, `idna` and `ipaddress`. After installing these (using simply `pip install` command), I was able to install `awscli`.

Answer (score 2):

None of the above answers worked for me. After hours of debugging I found this:

The package you are trying to install from upstream may not be distributed for your system's architecture or target Python version.

**Example:** If you're running on `aarch64` with `Python 3.12`, the upstream package index may only provide the `amd64` architecture up to `Python 3.11`. So you will see `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement <package>` error.

Please check the project's *compatibility matrix* (if there is any) or `Download files` section in `PyPI`.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem installing `pandas-1.4.3`, and the problem was my python patch version. `pandas-1.4.3` required python version `3.8.13` and did not work with `3.8.9`:

```
python install -r requirements.txt # or pip install pandas==1.4.3
# -> Could not find a version that satisfies...
conda activate my_project # creates a virtual env for a new python version
conda install python=3.8.13 # installing the new python version
python --version # displays 3.8.13
pip install -r python/requirements.txt
# -> pandas installed as expected
```

Answer (score 0):

Same error in slightly different circumstances, on MacOs. Apparently setuptools versions past 45 can expose some issues and this command got me past it:
`pip3 install setuptools==45`

Answer (score 0):

If the package is local, don't miss the **relative path**.
E.g.

```
pip install ./<pkg>
```

finally worked in my case, while

```
pip install <pkg>
```

yielded:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement <pkg> (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for <pkg>
```