# Installing the cube2sphere Python library

Tags: python

I'm beginner first trying Python. I'm trying to install a package `cube2sphere`, but I keep getting errors.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to include a copy the text from your terminal, not a screenshot.

Comment: There is no project on pypi named [cube2sphere](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=cube2sphere&submit=search). Are you sure you have the name right? Or are you trying to install it from somewhere else?

Comment: See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32302379/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-package

Comment: cube2sphere is Download this site :https://github.com/Xyene/cube2sphere   This is not Project?

Comment: I found this post by accident, but it looks like I forgot to upload the package to PyPi. I've done so now so pip install should work. If it doesn't, the issue page on Github is likely a more suitable place than StackOverflow to help debug your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any package/module called *cube2sphere*. Try to use **Xyene** and then implement cube2sphere using that.

The GitHub repository is [here](https://github.com/Xyene/cube2sphere). You can download the source from there and use also.

Comment: I already download that. But I don't know whether it should be located.

Comment: Locate it anywhere and find where you have to add the ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE