# convert cubemap to equirectangular with this Python script

Tags: python, pip, blender

I´m new to python and using scripts in general but do need to use the script below to convert 6 images to equirectangular.

https://github.com/Xyene/cube2sphere

The python version I use is 3.7.4 (same as in Blender). Pip is installed and added blender.exe to PATH too. I´m trying to install for Windows but the instructions are too scarce and don´t understand exactly what to do with the "Finally, pip install cube2sphere" instruction. Is it run from Blender´s console or Windows Command Prompt? Do i need to reference the folder where the script is saved? Do i need to save the script in a specific folder? Do i have to run Command window from the folder where the script is and then pip install cube2sphere?  Could anyone please give me more detailed instructions in order to use the script and then how am i supposed to make it work in Blender?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> Is it run from Blender´s console or Windows Command Prompt? Do i need
>   to reference the folder where the script is saved?

You just need to include the the path of blender executable and then Run

```
pip install cube2sphere
```

on windows Console.
You can also check this Question maybe you can find something.
[Here..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37289179/installing-the-cube2sphere-python-library)

Comment: thanks a lot. I am now getting an the except pkg_resources.VersionConflict, e: ERROR. I also filed a new issue in Github