# pip install docker failing

Tags: python, pip, python-venv

This question is related to [this one](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwiyiIPzw4TNAhXlDMAKHT2MCQAQFggiMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F18230956%2Fcould-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-pytz&usg=AFQjCNEij2uzMaIQUQQFiQC-gcSHOL0JHg) and [this one](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwiyiIPzw4TNAhXlDMAKHT2MCQAQFggrMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F32302379%2Fcould-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-package&usg=AFQjCNGKO7RVfbZ2DROhxtIiNnRSLRBcHw). I am trying to install and run docker(-compose) in a newly created python virtual environment:

```
$ mkdir temp_venv
$ cd temp_venv
$ virtualenv venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv) $ pip list
pip (8.1.2)
setuptools (21.2.2)
wheel (0.29.0)
```

**docker-compose** installs successfully through pip, but when I try to install docker the following error is thrown:

```
(venv) $ pip install docker
Collecting docker
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement docker (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for docker
```

Trying to install with the **--pre** flag set returns the same error. Also, when trying to run docker in venv the following error is given:

```
WARNING: The "bootstrap" service specifies a port on the host. If multiple containers for this service are created on a single host, the port will clash.
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon. You might need to install Docker:
```

Installing **docker-compose** with **pip2** gives the same error (the same goes for docker:

```
Collecting docker
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)",)': /simple/docker/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement docker (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for docker
).
```

Comment: I think you're supposed to install docker from [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/) instead of using `pip`. If you mean to install `docker-py`, you could do `pip install docker-py`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32302379/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-package

Comment: This is the general error message for a package that don't exist, since docker is not a python package. Have you read the install doc on the docker site?

Comment: I've seen it now; I confused docker with a python module.