# Upgrade the Python package dateutil: Could not find a version

Tags: python, pip, upgrade, macos-sierra, python-dateutil

I tried to upgrade `dateutil` from `2.5.3` to the newest version `2.6.0` with `pip install dateutil --upgrade`, but got the issue `Could not find a version`.

```
$ pip install dateutil --upgrade
Collecting dateutil
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dateutil (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for dateutil
```

I checked the post [Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32302379/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-package) . Running `pip freeze | grep dateutil` got,

```
$ pip freeze | grep dateutil
python-dateutil==2.5.3
```

How do I know which version satisfies my machine? Is it possible to upgrade `dateutil` to the newest version?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

It is

```
pip install python-dateutil --upgrade
```

Comment: Thank you. `sudo pip install python-dateutil --upgrade` works for me.

Comment: Thank you, it's nothing but '--upgrade'.

Comment: this command worked for me. Thank you