# Unable to install using pip install requirements.txt

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, requirements.txt

I'm trying to install [BitTornado](https://github.com/effigies/BitTornado/tree/python2.7) for Python 2.7 using requirements.txt, I get the following error:

```
Collecting requirements.txt
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requirements.txt (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for requirements.txt
```

Here is my code in requirements.txt:

```
-e git+https://github.com/effigies/BitTornado.git#egg=python2.7
```

I also tried `-e git+https://github.com/effigies/BitTornado.git@python2.7` but it still is not working. Does someone know why is this happening?

Note: "python2.7" is the branch name

Comment: Please show the exact pip command you ran.

Comment: It's "pip install requirements.txt"

Comment: `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: Thanks @mic4ael. I don't know how I missed -r argument!

Answer (score 322, accepted):

The correct command is `pip install -r requirements.txt`.  Note the `-r` option; without it, pip thinks you want to install a package named `requirements.txt`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks @jwodder, with -r option, it says git command not found. Does it mean I have to install git on my system and without it, it can not be installed?

Comment: @AvdheshParashar: Yes.

Comment: Is there any other way I could install git hosted library without having to use command `git clone ....`. I also tried dependency_links in setup.py but it is deprecated now.

Comment: @AvdheshParashar: Go to https://github.com/effigies/BitTornado, click "Clone or download", click "Download ZIP", and run `pip install /path/to/zip/file/you/just/downloaded`

Comment: Thanks @jwodder, I did that already but I want to install it using code, not manually

Comment: @AvdheshParashar: `pip install https://github.com/effigies/BitTornado/archive/python2.7.zip`

Comment: You saved me :D

Answer (score 20):

You forgot to add `-r` switch to specify that `requirements.txt` is the file with your dependencies.