# Error Installing nltk module in python 2.7 64 bit

Tags: nltk

Hi when i try to install nltk mpodule on python through command
pip install nltk i get the error
Error is shown in image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPXJh.png)

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/alvations/0ed8641d7d2e1941b9f9

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32302379/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-package) ?