# Collecting pyarrow.io ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyarrow.io (from versions: none)

Tags: python, installation, pyarrow

I am trying to install pyarrow.io and pyarrow.parquet to be able to read parquet files and convert them to jsons.

When I do :

```
pip install pyarrow.io --user
```

I get:

```
Collecting pyarrow.io
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyarrow.io (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyarrow.io
```

Is there anything else I can try? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```py
pip install pyarrow
# OR
python -m pip install pyarrow
```

see:

- https://pyarrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html
- [Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement <package>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32302379/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-package)