# How to install feature_engine python package?

Tags: python, package

I want to install Feature-engine package on Kaggle to use YeoJohnsonTransformer.

I have some questions about feature-engine ([reference](https://readthedocs.org/projects/feature-engine/downloads/pdf/latest/)):
1- to install the package, this document recommends:
`pip install feature-engine`

The feature-engine is with **hyphen** in the above code, however when calling it, it comes with **underscore**:
`from feature_engine import variable_transformers as vt`
Is that correct?

2- how can I fix the following error while installing the package?

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement feature-engine (from versions: none)

Thank you,

p.s. I could not create a new tag for feature-engine because" creating the new tag 'feature-engine' requires at least 1500 reputation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install the package use: `pip install feature_engine`. Follow this [link](https://pypi.org/project/feature-engine/) to the index.

Then the command from `feature_engine import variable_transformers as vt` should work.

If you continue having trouble with the requirements, check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32302379/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-package).