# feature_engine package's modules not getting imported in Kaggle

Tags: python, machine-learning, kaggle

Can not import feature_engine package's module in Kaggle Editor.

(First noting the below lines of codes are working in local machine's Jupyter Notebook, but not in Kaggle )

**To Reproduce, I did below inside Kaggle Editor**

To install `feature_engine` just the regular code

`!pip install feature_engine`

following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63863747/1902852) link which is same as the [official doc](https://pypi.org/project/feature-engine/).

And then I just have the following code in Kaggle Notebook per the [official documentation](https://feature-engine.readthedocs.io/en/0.6.x_a/encoders/OneHotCategoricalEncoder.html?highlight=OneHotCategoricalEncoder)

```py
from feature_engine import categorical_encoders as ce
```

After running this cell getting below error.

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'categorical_encoders' from 'feature_engine' (/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/feature_engine/__init__.py)
```

And this error is coming for any modules of `feature_engine` . e.g. for the below line as well

```py
from feature_engine import variable_transformers as vt
```

I am getting error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'variable_transformers' from 'feature_engine' (/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/feature_engine/__init__.py)
```

And there's no simple way to upgrade Python to 3.8, as Kaggle does not allow us to specify the python version in it's notebook.

In Kaggle I have the latest version of `feature_engine` as running `!pip show feature_engine` gives below

```
Name: feature-engine
Version: 1.0.2
Summary: Feature engineering package with Scikit-learn's fit transform functionality
Home-page: http://github.com/solegalli/feature_engine
Author: Soledad Galli
Author-email: solegalli@protonmail.com
License: BSD 3 clause
Location: /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: scipy, pandas, statsmodels, scikit-learn, numpy
Required-by:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question after finding the solution.

Basically, I had to upgrade the version of `feature_engine`

**Feature-engine** is in active development regularly publishing new or updated transformers. Hence, ran below to upgrade

```
$ pip install -U feature-engine
```

In new version (1.0), we need to import categorical encoders from feature_engine.encoding as below

```
from feature_engine.encoding import OneHotEncoder
```

The format below is not used anymore :

```
from feature_engine import categorical_encoders as ce
```

[Official Doc](https://feature-engine.readthedocs.io/en/1.0.x/index.html)