# pip ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement freeze==1.0.10

Tags: python, pip

I just cloned a repository and tried to install all the required packages when I got this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement freeze==1.0.10
```

I searched all over and could not find any specific answer having to do with freeze==1.0.10.  Other posts showed similar errors such as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32302379/3549766). What does the error say, what is causing it, and how to resolve this?

Comment: Could you please provide the pip command you are running?

Comment: What a repository? what required packages?

Comment: @user1010 pip install -r requirements.txt

Comment: @phd Just a repository on github.  It is a private repository from work. Packages means all the required packages listed in requirements.txt

Comment: Without any information how do you expect us to help?

Comment: Are you able to share the contents of requirements.txt?

Comment: I simply removed freeze==1.0.10 from the list of required packages and have yet to run into an issue. I'll see if I can share the content of requirements.txt