# pip error no module named traceback: "Couldn't find a version that satisfies the requirement traceback (from versions: none)"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Today I updated to pip 21.1.1, I installed opencv and tqdm libraries I didn't have problems, but later when I tried to install traceback gives me this error:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement traceback (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for traceback

[This is a image of what happened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syYza.png)

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32302379/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-package should help.

Answer (score 2):

1. `traceback` is not available on `pip`, and if you search for it on [PyPi](https://pypi.org/search/?q=traceback), the closest thing you find is [`traceback2`](https://pypi.org/project/traceback2/), *"a backport of traceback to older supported Pythons."*
2. This is because the `traceback` module is part of the [Python standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html)

Comment: That solves a lot of questions, but why i dont have traceback in my python installed libraries?, the same happend to me with shutil

Comment: Everyone should have the standard library (that's kinda the point), so maybe something is wrong with yours. What specifically are you typing, and what error do you get?

Comment: I was only trying to import traceback library, but when i run the programm, give me the error that traceback library is not installed

Comment: @JoacoMonsalvo I think you should reinstall Python.

Answer (score -1):

there isn't a traceback module, that's why