# matplotlib does not upgrade beyound 3.2.1

Tags: python, matplotlib, upgrade, azure-machine-learning-service

I am using Notebook on Azure Machine Learning Studio and I am trying to install latest version of matplotlib, but it continues using version 3.2.1 I tried conda, pip, and also tried to uninstall and install again, nothing works.
sample commands tried:

```
!pip install matplotlib
!conda install matplotlib
```

Am I missing sth? thanks

Comment: Did you try `!pip install matplotlib==3.2.2`?

Comment: so it says  it successfully installed 3.2.2. but when I check for the version number still says 3.2.1.

Comment: Also when I tried to install version 3.4.2, I got following error:   ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement matplotlib==3.4.2 (from versions: 0.86, 0.86.1, 0.86.2, 0.91.0, 0.91.1, 1.0.1, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.4.0, 1.4.1rc1, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, ...0rc1, 3.3.0, 3.3.1, 3.3.2, 3.3.3, 3.3.4)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for matplotlib==3.4.2

Comment: You may want to check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32302379/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-package

Comment: matplotlib version will be depending on the python version using. Currently higher version of matplotlib 3.5 will be available for python version 3.7. Kindly check the version of python. 3.2 version of matplotlib will be available from python version 3.6.

Comment: thanks, you are right, it was set on python 3.6. but even when I changed the kernel to python 3.8 AzureML, it was still using python 3.6 when I checked for python version. I tried upgrading python, still the same! so weird!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of **Matplotlib** will depend on the version of python. There is no support for the latest version of matplotlib library for **python version 3.8**. The latest version of matplotlib can be available only up to **3.7 version** of python. Even though we tried to upgrade it with **pip, conda** , by default **version of python program**, it will take the supporting version of matplotlib.

For the current version of matplotlib in the current case of the situation, it is **3.2**. It is suggestable to check the version of python, whether it is 3.6 or not. **Python version 3.6 supports 3.2 and 3.1 versions of matplotlib**.

If still the python version is showing the latest version of python, try to **degrade** the version and check.